# Prop: If two functions $f,g$ are bijective, their compositions are also bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prop:** If two functions $f,g$ are bijective, their compositions are also bijective.

**Pf:** Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. By definition, an injective function is invertible.  $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$. Since $g$ is a bijection, $f(f^{-1}(x)) = f(f^{-1}(y)) \implies x = y$. Then, $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ is a bijection.

Conversely, $g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \implies g(g^{-1}(x))=g(g^{-1}(y)) \implies x =y$.

$g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ is also a bijection as required.

Comment: Injective functions only admit a partial inverse, consider the identity function of the naturals to the reals

Answer (score 3):

Without using inverses (otherwise note that $(g \circ f)^{-1}= f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ and be done with it), just definitions:

$(g \circ f)$ is injective: suppose $(g \circ f)(x)= (g \circ f)(x')$, so $g(f(x))=g(f(x'))$ and because $g$ is injective, $f(x)=f(x')$ and then as $f$ is injective too, $x=x'$.

$(g \circ f)$ is surjective: let $z$ be any point in the codomain of $g$ which is also the codomain of $(g \circ f)$. Then there is some $y \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$ such that $g(y)=z$ as $g$ is surjective, and that $y$ is also in the codomain of $f$ (or the composition wouldn't be defined) so there is some $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(g \circ f)$ with $f(x)=y$ ($f$ is surjective).

But then $(g \circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=g(y)=z$ as required.